# Обмен данными между сокетами

Tags: c++, python, сокет

Написал сокет-сервер на python (ubuntu), а клиента на c++ (windows). Проблема в том, что на сервере функция recv требует оповещение об закрытиии сокета (shutdown) от клиента, иначе на этом месте скрипт останавливается. Если же я вызову shutdown на стороне клиента, сервер примет сообщение и отправит ответное, но клиент-сокет больше не сможет ни отправлять, ни получать данные (из-за этого shutdown). А мне нужно обмениваться данными в цикле.

Вот примерно так:

клиент:

```
 1.инициализация сокета
 2. подключение к серверу
 3. отправка данных
 4. получение ответа от сервера
 5. отправка данных
 6. получение ответа от сервера  ...
 55. закрытие соединения
```

server.py:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((host, port))

sock.listen(10)

while 1:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print('new connection from ' + addr[0] + ":" + str(addr[1]))

    data = bytearray()

    while 1:
        while 1:
            chunk = conn.recv(128)

            if not chunk:
                break
            else:
                data += chunk

        print(str(len(data)) + " bytes received (" + data.decode('ascii', 'strict') + ")")

        date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())

        bytes_len = conn.send(date.encode('ascii'))
        print(str(bytes_len) + " bytes sent")

    print('closing the connection..')
    conn.close()

sock.close()
```

client.exe:

```
int send_data(SOCKET sock, const char* data, int datalen)
{
    int bytes_len = send(sock, data, datalen, 0);

    if (bytes_len < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    /*if (shutdown(sock, SD_SEND) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }*/

    return bytes_len;
}

int recv_data(SOCKET sock, char* buf)
{
    log("0");
    int recvlen = 0;

    char chunk[128];
    memset(chunk, 0, sizeof(chunk));

    do {
        log("1");
        int len = recv(sock, chunk, sizeof(chunk), 0);
        log("2");
        if (len == -1)
            return -1;

        if (len == 0)
        {
            /*if (shutdown(sock, SD_RECEIVE) < 0) {
                return -1;
            }*/

            return recvlen;
        }

        memcpy(buf + recvlen, chunk, len);
        memset(chunk, 0, sizeof(chunk));

        recvlen += len;

    } while (true);
}

void force()
{
    char* ip = "";
    int port = 0;

    int result;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    log("socket startup..");
    result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    if (result != 0) {
        log("wsastartup failed: %d", result);
        return;
    }

    log("creating socket..");
    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        log("error creating socket: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    log("connecting to %s:%d", ip, port);
    result = connect(sock, (sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        log("Unnable to connect to server: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        string msg = "hello from windows " + to_string(i);

        int bytes_len = send_data(sock, msg.c_str(), msg.length());

        if (bytes_len < 0)
        {
            log("Error sending data: %d", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(sock);
            WSACleanup();
            return;
        }

        log("%d bytes sent..", bytes_len);

        char buf[1024];
        memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

        bytes_len = recv_data(sock, buf);

        if (bytes_len < 0)
        {
            log("Error receiving data: %d", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(sock);
            WSACleanup();
            return;
        }

        log("%d bytes received (%s)", bytes_len, buf);
    }

    log("socket closing..");
    closesocket(sock);

    log("wsa cleanup..");
    WSACleanup();

    return;
}
```

Comment: *"на этом месте скрипт останавливается"* - так наверное надо делать обработку ошибок каким-то образом, не?

Comment: > _функция recv требует оповещение об закрытиии сокета_

Что значит "требует" в данном контексте?

Comment: @VTT, это нормальное поведение функции, ф-я recv останавливает скрипт и ждет данные, но проблема в том, что когда она их получает, она не возобновляет скрипт, пока не получит shutdown() со стороны клиента, а должна дальше возобновлять работу скрипта. По крайней мере, в документациях я такого не находил

Comment: @isnullxbh, не дает дальше исполняться скрипту, пока не получит shutdown() со стороны клиента. Хотя так быть не должно, я не знаю в чем проблема. Если использовать shutdown(), то все работает, данные получаются и скрипт дальше исполняется, но в таком случае и клиентский сокет сворачивается и дальше его использовать нельзя.

Comment: @saulgdmn, покажите версию кода серверной части вместе с вызовом ф-ии shutdown.

Comment: @isnullxbh, все точно так-же

Comment: @saulgdmn, все, понял, извините, все увидел :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Сервер ожидает, что ему придет от клиента 128 байт данных:</s>

```
chunk = conn.recv(128)
```

Клиент отправляет явно меньше:

```
string msg = "hello from windows " + to_string(i);
```

Вызов `conn.recv(128)` - блокирующий, т.е., если в буфере сокета нет данных - он будет ждать.

**Спасибо @jfs за замечание**

Когда Вы вызываете `shutdown(sock, SD_RECEIVE)` отправляется пакет с сегментом FIN (на самом деле их отправляется несколько) - и тогда read возвращает ноль (EOF - с данного сокета вы больше не можете читать данные):

```
if not chunk:
                break
```

Что в итоге позволяет выйти из цикла.

Comment: Вы верно меня поняли. Но как это обойти?

Comment: @saulgdmn, тут уже Вам нужно думать, потому что это зависит от задачи. Можете передавать в первых четырех байтах размер посылки. Можете реалиовать полноценный протокол (размер сообщения завсит от его типа). В общем, учтите, что ни серверная сторона, ни клиентская ничего не знают о размере посылки с противоположной стороны.

Comment: благодарю за ответ)

Comment: @saulgdmn: fyi, `conn.recv(128)` не обязан ждать полные 128 байт. Этот вызов может вернуться прочитав только один байт. 128 это размер буфера, а не размер результата: `1 <= len(chunk) <= 128`.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо огромное за замечание, ведь действительно, данное поведение ничем не отличается от поведения системного вызова recv. Спасибо!

Comment: можно ещё добавить, что `len(chunk)==0` означает EOF (больше данных с этого сокета вы не прочтёте)

Comment: @jfs, спасибо, сейчас добавлю )